# Why won't my delegate accept performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, delegates

Xcode 4 is giving me compiler warnings on the `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` message sent to my delegate and I don't get it.

My delegate is declared like:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <AccountFeedbackDelegate> delegate;
```

And then eventually executed on the main thread:

```
[self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didChangeCloudStatus) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Yet Xcode persists on giving me:

> *warning: Semantic Issue: Method '-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')*

Of course the code compiles and runs fine, but I don't like the warning. When I redeclare the delegate like this, the warning vanishes, but I don't like the workaround:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSObject <AccountFeedbackDelegate> *delegate;
```

What am I missing? What did I do wrong?
Cheers,
EP

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` is declared in a category on `NSObject` in NSThread.h. Since your variable is of type `id`, the compiler cannot be certain that it can respond to a message defined for `NSObject`. And unlike with plain `id` variables, the compiler warns you about this when your variable is declared `id <SomeProtocol>`.

So you should indeed declare your delegate as `NSObject <AccountFeedbackDelegate>`.

PS: The "standard" way to get rid of this kind of warning by declaring the protocol as `@protocol AccountFeedbackDelegate <NSObject>` won't work here because `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` is not declared in the `NSObject` protocol.

Comment: Thanks for that one @Ole, that indeed explains it. I'll keep declaring the delegate with id, but cast it to NSObject before calling the `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` method.

Comment: NSObject <AccountFeedbackDelegate> *propertyName